# Shorted similar commands in PHP function

Tags: php, function

I want to short this function. I have also published a little part of it, but it is every time the same principle:

```
if(in_array($infinitiveVerb,
    IrregularExceptionGroup::$name_in_lowercase)) {
        $exceptionmodel = ExceptionModel::NAME_IN_UPPERCASE; 
}
```

**php function**

```
function finding_exception_model(InfinitiveVerb $infinitiveVerb)
{
    $exceptionmodel = ExceptionModel::NO_EXCEPTIONS;
    if (in_array($infinitiveVerb, IrregularExceptionGroup::$aller)) {
        $exceptionmodel = ExceptionModel::ALLER;
    }
    if (in_array($infinitiveVerb, IrregularExceptionGroup::$avoir_irr)) {
        $exceptionmodel = ExceptionModel::AVOIR_IRR;
    }
    if (in_array($infinitiveVerb, IrregularExceptionGroup::$etre_irr)) {
        $exceptionmodel = ExceptionModel::ETRE_IRR;
    }
    return new ExceptionModel($exceptionmodel);
}
```

**ExceptionModel.php**

```
class ExceptionModel extends Enum
{    
    const NO_EXCEPTIONS = 'no exceptions';
    const ALLER = 'aller';   
    const AVOIR_IRR = 'avoir_irr';   
    const ETRE_IRR = 'etre_irr';
}
```

How is this possible?

Comment: what exactly is the question? I have no idea what youre asking.

Comment: You know that you overwrite the variable in every if statement if it enters it? Are you sure you don't want if/elseif ?

Comment: I don't want to have similar if conditions, because they are very similar. How to use one if condition for all `ExceptionModel`s.

Comment: @Rizier123 I am not very sure, but the function works like it should.

Comment: @Grischa If the variable `$infinitiveVerb` is in the irregular aller array, then you set the variable to an "ALLER" exception. But if `$infinitiveVerb` is also in the irregular etre_irr array, then you overwrite the variable and set it to an "ETRE_IRR" exception. Are you sure you want this? And not an if/elseif, where when you enter one if statement, you don't access the other ones.

Comment: @Rizier123 `$infinitiveVerb` is an array, not a variable and it isn't in any irregular arrays.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can see and would change here, is to just put every irregularExceptionGroup into an array, like this:

```
function finding_exception_model(InfinitiveVerb $infinitiveVerb)
{

    $exceptionmodel = ExceptionModel::NO_EXCEPTIONS;

    $irregularExceptionGroupArray = [
            ExceptionModel::ALLER => IrregularExceptionGroup::$aller,
            ExceptionModel::AVOIR_IRR => IrregularExceptionGroup::$avoir_irr,
            ExceptionModel::ETRE_IRR => IrregularExceptionGroup::$etre_irr,
        ];

    foreach($irregularExceptionGroupArray as $exceptionModel => $irregularExceptionGroup){
        if(in_array($infinitiveVerb, $irregularExceptionGroup)){
            $exceptionmodel = $exceptionModel;
            //break; //If you don't want to overwrite the variable, just uncomment this
        }
    }

    return new ExceptionModel($exceptionmodel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine all exceptions into one lookup, instead of this in_array checks all the time. (Note: IF off course the InfinitVerb has a __toString of some kind)

For example `IrregularExceptionGroup::$aller` contains: `['aller', 'allez', 'je suis', 'paris']` and `IrregularExceptionGroup::$avoir_irr` contains `['some', 'more', 'stuff']`

Change it to:

```
IrregularExceptionGroup::$allExceptions = [
    'aller' => ExceptionModel::ALLER,
    'allez' => ExceptionModel::ALLER,
    'je suis' => ExceptionModel::ALLER,
    'paris' => ExceptionModel::ALLER,
    'some'  => ExceptionModel::AVOIR_IRR,
    'more'  => ExceptionModel::AVOIR_IRR,
    'stuff'  => ExceptionModel::AVOIR_IRR
];


function finding_exception_model(InfinitiveVerb $infinitiveVerb)
{
    $ex = ExceptionModel::NO_EXCEPTIONS;
    if (array_key_exists($infinitiveVerb, IrregularExceptionGroup::$allExceptions)) {
        $ex = IrregularExceptionGroup::$allExceptions[$infinitiveVerb];
    }

    return new ExceptionModel($ex);
}
```

And you could even make it "shorter" by using the ternary operator:

```
function finding_exception_model(InfinitiveVerb $infinitiveVerb)
{
    return new ExceptionModel(isset(IrregularExceptionGroup::$allExceptions[$infinitiveVerb]) ? IrregularExceptionGroup::$allExceptions[$infinitiveVerb] : ExceptionModel::NO_EXCEPTIONS);
}
```

or PHP 7:

```
function finding_exception_model(InfinitiveVerb $infinitiveVerb)
{
    return new ExceptionModel( IrregularExceptionGroup::$allExceptions[$infinitiveVerb] ?? ExceptionModel::NO_EXCEPTIONS);
}
```